# How to deploy application in bluemix from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

When I try to deploy application to bluemix, I get following error

```
Error: Host taken error. A different mapped application URL is required before pushing or starting the application.
```

Though If I download a default application created bluemix, download the same and import in eclipse and then redeploying application works fine. I am sure I must be missing some key steps, wondering if someone can point me to the link that has those details or missing step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the screenshot below to ensure that your mapped URL is correct:

[image: MappedURL Pic]

Answer (score 0):

according to the posted error you just set a wrong URL for your app's mapping URL: just check on Eclipse Server view, you should have Bluemix Server item, double click on it to open, it should show your server configuration, go to Applications and Services tab, here you could find you app listed; now double click on it, it should open you app properties, check on Mapper URL property under General configuration tab.
Otherwise could you provide some details more about the configuration used on Bluemix Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding..
application name is globle. what ever application name using that already used by someone.
try to change Name.
ex:- cocacola.mybluemix.net change to cocacola429.mybluemix.net.

it worked for me.